# How to call this JS function that is set to a variable in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, module-pattern

I have a function like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var funct = (function(){
        var foo = 1;

        function getPrivateVariable(){
            return foo;
        }

        return {
            getFoo: getPrivateVariable
        };
    })();
});
```

Then I try to type `funct.getFoo();` into the console of firebug and it says "funct is undefined". How come or how can I call this function in console. If it is not possible in this form(I am using a [module design pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)), then why is it not possible?

Comment: depends on where this code is being executed. If it's executed in the global scope, it would be available in the console.

Comment: I tried the same thing and found its working fine

Comment: weird working is just fine for me

Comment: @volkinc hmm i scaled the example down to a simple one from the exact problem, but the answer below solved my problem. So my function wasn't defined in the global scope because it was in a closure like DJDavid98's answer states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the function is defined on the global scope, because if it's inside a closure, the console won't see it. Instead of this:

```
var funct = (function(){
```

use

```
window.funct = (function(){
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. So my function was defined in a closure. Is the self-executing function creating the closure or is it something else?

Comment: It wasn't necessarily defined in a closure, but it was inside another function, and thus it was defined in a scope that was not the global scope. This can happen for example if you have your code inside `$(document).ready(function{ ... })`

Comment: Ooooo ya it is wrapped up in that. Ill update my example to show that too

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to window.funct vs var funct and it will be accessible from everywhere.